# pagination is not working in codeigniter :(

Tags: php, pagination, codeigniter-2

I want to display 2 rows in view page as an output. Again when i click on to go to the next page it will display 2 next rows and so on ( All together I have 8 rows in 
            table). But when I run the following code it displays all 8 rows in the view-page along with pagination links. I tried whole day to find the actual reason for not
            working it but my problem is still unsolved. I searched for the help on internet with related query but it was of no use. Finalyy I am here with my own words to explain
            the problem. I've commented almost all the lines in my code. I am loading libraries in autoload for pagination and helper for form and url. I'll really be thankful if
            somebody help me out. Thanks in advance.

```
   <?php
        class ManageUser extends CI_Controller {  // creating class for the controller
            function index()
            {
                if($this->session->userdata('logged_in'))  // checking users under session if he is already logged in
                {           
                    $this->load->model('admin/user');     // loading model . I am not using Datamapper.
                    $result = $this->user->view_user();   // getting response from the model and storing it to result
                    $total_rows = count($result);         // counting number of rows countered ( its 8 in in my database ) 
                    //echo $total_rows;


                    if($result)
                    {
                        $data['users'] = $result;
                        $config['base_url'] = "http://192.168.0.102/project/index.php/admin/manageUser";  // this is the address where I am pointing the view page url
                        $config['total_rows'] = $total_rows;        // Total numbers of rows assigned to pagination-config
                        $config['per_page'] = '2';                  // I want to display 2 rows in 1 page
                        $config['uri_segment'] = '2';
                        $this->pagination->initialize($config);     // initilizing the pagination-config
                        //$data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();  
                        //$this->load->vars($data);
                        $this->load->view('admin/manageUser',$data);  // Loading the page
                    }

                    //$this->load->view('admin/manageUser',$data);
                }
                else
                {
                    redirect('admin/login');    // incase of faliured session user will be redirected to the login-page.
                }
            }
        }
        ?>
```

Following code is from my model named User

```
 <?php
            Class User extends CI_Model   // extending the model
            {
                function __construct()
                {
                    parent::__construct();
                }

                function view_user()        // function which is loaded from controller
                {

                    $query = $this -> db -> get('users');  //query to fetch all the information from the database
                    return $query->result();        // returning result to the Controller.
                }
            }
        ?>
```

And finally this is the view page I am using to display the content .

```
  <!-- This is the view page -->

        <?php if(isset($users)) { ?>     <!-- Checking if user is set -->
             <?php foreach($users as $user) { ?>  <!-- running in a loop to accept all the value from the database and display it row wise -->
                <td><?php echo $user -> us_display_name; ?></td>   <!-- Displaying name -->
                <td><?php echo $user -> us_first_name . " " . $user -> us_last_name; ?></td> <!-- Displaying first name and last name together -->
                <td><?php echo $user -> us_email_id; ?></td>  <!-- Displaying email-ID -->
        <?php } } else { ?>
        <tr>    <td>No records found!</td>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php echo $this->pagination->create_links(); ?>
```

Comment: you need to define the offset and limit in your query....

Comment: I did with that also. But its not working. Please check the codes below. <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
function index($offset = 0)
    {         
  $this->load->model('user');
  $this->load->library('pagination');        
        $user_list = new user();
        $total_rows = $user_list->count();
 
        //$student_list->order_by('name');        
        $data['user_list'] = $user_list->get(5, $offset)->all;

Comment: thanks a lot for replying. when I load the page it shows all the rows. it creates the pagination links but when I click on the link it displays an error page says page is not found.

Comment: http://www.weblee.co.uk/2009/06/06/codeigniter-pagination-part-1/  please check the above link which I am referring at the moment. I pasted my code yesterday itself but got no reply but I kept searching for the relevant code. I found this one and trying to implement this new code. It wont take much time for u to go through.  It allows you to download the code too. I just implemented it in my CI and found this error : Unable to load the requested file: inc/header.php

Comment: the code i get from your link has basic syntax problem like you didnt load the model in your controller (possible you have added in autoload.php) and you are using wrong name too in controller, your model name is postsmodel but you are referring to posts which is itself a controllers name

Comment: oh ok. then what can be the possible errors with the above code. The above code I am keeping safe for work out. If you can suggest something then I will go through once again. My problem is still unsolved from last 27 hours. I am really tensed as it is a pert of one of my project.

Comment: change your uri segment to 3, 2 is the name of method or you can remove it as codeigniter automatically detects which uri segment to use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting all the users from the Model. That's not how you do it. 
Your controller should be something like this :

```
<?php
    class ManageUser extends CI_Controller {  // creating class for the controller
        function index($offset)
        {
            if($this->session->userdata('logged_in'))  // checking users under session if he is already logged in
            {           
                $this->load->model('admin/user');     // loading model . I am not using Datamapper.
                $perpage = 2;

                $result = $this->user->view_user($offset,$perpage);   // getting response from the model and storing it to result
                $total_rows = $this->db->count_all('users');


                if($result)
                {
                    $data['users'] = $result;
                    $config['base_url'] = "http://192.168.0.102/project/index.php/admin/manageUser";  // this is the address where I am pointing the view page url
                    $config['total_rows'] = $total_rows;        // Total numbers of rows assigned to pagination-config
                    $config['per_page'] = $perpage;                  // I want to display 2 rows in 1 page
                    $config['uri_segment'] = '2';
                    $this->pagination->initialize($config);     // initilizing the pagination-config
                    //$data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();  
                    //$this->load->vars($data);
                    $this->load->view('admin/manageUser',$data);  // Loading the page
                }

                //$this->load->view('admin/manageUser',$data);
            }
            else
            {
                redirect('admin/login');    // incase of faliured session user will be redirected to the login-page.
            }
        }
    }
    ?>
```

And in the model you need to limit the result

```
 <?php
        Class User extends CI_Model   // extending the model
        {
            function __construct()
            {
                parent::__construct();
            }

            function view_user($offset,$limit)        // function which is loaded from controller
            {

                $query = $this -> db -> get('users',$perpage,$offset);  //You dont fetch all the data from the database
                return $query->result();        // returning result to the Controller.
            }
        }
    ?>
```