# inconsistent amount of data when I use pagination in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, codeigniter-form-helper

I want to perform a large of data using paging library in CodeIgniter. I have been implementing it and it works. But, I have a problem - amount of data per page is not consistent.

This is the simple code how Imade it...

Controller

```
class Buku_con extends Controller {

    public function Buku_con() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('buku_model');
        $this->load->library('pagination'); //call pagination library
    }

    function getBuku() {
        //count the total rows of tb_book
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('tb_book');
        $getData = $this->db->get('');
        $a = $getData->num_rows();
        $config['base_url'] = base_url().'index.php/Buku_con/getBuku/'; //set the base url for pagination
        $config['total_rows'] = $a; //total rows
        $config['per_page'] = '10'; //the number of per page for pagination
        $config['uri_segment'] = 3; //see from base_url. 3 for this case
        $config['full_tag_open'] = '<p>';
        $config['full_tag_close'] = '</p>';
        $this->pagination->initialize($config); //initialize pagination
        $data['detail'] = $this->buku_model->getBuku($config['per_page'],$this->uri->segment(3));
        $this->load->view('buku_view', $data);
    }

}
```

Model

```
class Buku_model extends Model {

    function Buku_model() {
        parent::Model();
    }

    function getBuku($perPage,$uri) { //to get all data in tb_book
        $title=$this->session->userdata('title');
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('tb_book');
        $this->db->where('title','$title');
        $this->db->order_by('id','DESC');
        $getData = $this->db->get('', $perPage, $uri);
        if($getData->num_rows() > 0)
            return $getData->result_array();
        else
            return null;
    }
}
```

View

```
if(count($detail) > 0) { 

//... html for table .....

foreach($detail as $rows) {
    echo 
    .... $rows['id'] .....
    .... $rows['title'] .....
    .... $rows['author'] .....
    ....
} 
echo $this->pagination->create_links(); ....
```

The paging works well, but amount of data per page is not consistent like I define in controller. I think the problem is caused by the query that I use in model -  Session of title.

I want the data perform 10 data per page, but in page 1 just 5 data, page 2 just 4 data - not consistent. Maybe the problem is also in the view. What should I do? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

you have not properly calculated the offset. You may try this:

```
$offset = ( $this->uri->segment(3) - 1 ) * $config['per_page']; 

$data['detail'] = $this->buku_model->getBuku($config['per_page'], $offset);
```

Answer (score 0):

you might wanna look at this for proper pagination using codeigniter Pagination Library
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10123424/876117

You don't get all the data for each request. You need to fetch only data as specified the offset in the link generated by the pagination library.

Answer (score 0):

Dude, there is a lot of queries on your Controller. And also on Model (of corse).

First: Try to consume almost only functions on your controller. Functions that you create on a model. Thats is the right MVC way.

And about your problem with pagination:

Try to use and abuse of GET variables. Kind, you can pass a url like that:
http://site.com/controller/function?p=2

See? "?p=2"? That way I can say to my controller that I want to see the second page os the list. You know, I can pass more GET variables, like: 
http://site.com/controller/function?p=2&cat=romance&year=2010

And theres the way you will work these variables:

Lets take the second exemple ("?p=2&cat=romance&year=2010")

```
$page = $this->input->get('p'); // this is more secure too. avoid use $_GET or $_POST
$category = $this->input->get('cat');
$year = $this->input->get('year');
```

Now you can use some functions to get a list of books that matches to the values:

```
$data['books'] = $this->book->get_by_search($page, $category, $year);
```

PS: On this example, you got load a model 'book'that holds a function called 'get_by_search'. You have to do it to get the code working.

Tip: We never know how many variables a search can get. So you can create some model functions that receives those possible variables. Look:
//model Book

```
public function get_by_search($page = NULL, $cat = NULL, $year = NULL, $author = NULL)
{
    $perpage = 10;
    // the NULL is to prevent an error if the function is called without them.
    if ( ! is_numeric($page) || $page < 0)
    {
        $qtd    = $perpage;
        $offset = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        $qtd    = $page * perpage;
        $offset = $perpage;
    }
    $this->db->where('category', $cat);
    $this->db->where('year', $year);
    return $this->db->get('books', $perpage, $offset);
    // if you want to debug your queries, do the same above, but with no return
    // and then use this:
    echo this->db->last_query(); die; // stop here and see the query string.
}
```

well, I hope that it can help you. There is more to tell you but I think that its better you tell me more about your progress with the code. This answer is just a part of the solution. See? thats is not that simple, but I know how. Let me know here if you need more help, ok?

Um abraço!